# the ability to modify a string that is stored inside pointer and modify array, what is the different?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, memory, memory-management

I have two pointer (str) and another (str1), the first str is a pointer store string (char *str = "hello") and (char str1[]= "hello"). during one code I try to modify the values that stored inside this two pointers . I can change the value that is stored inside str1, but I can't do the same inside str.

After some research I get that the first pointer point to read memory only and the second is store the address of the write memory so I can't modify.

and I also I get at the end that the pointer is just store the address of some memory. so here in str1 after declare this str1[] that's mean str1 it is pointer store the address that can make me access to this location of this string

the question here is : Anyone can confirm this information if it is true. and if it false can someone explain what is happen exactly, and what's I need to learn about this things to master memory management.

Comment: Your `str1` is an array, not a pointer.  It's size and contents are initialized from the string literal given as its initializer.  It is a separate object from the string literal.

Comment: The pointer itself doesn't make the pointee unmodifiable – in your given case it is the assignment of a string *literal* to the pointer that causes the trouble. These literals are not modifiable, albeit not being of type `char const[]`. To avoid any trouble arising from don't ever assign literals to pointers to non-const.